# How can I show in a label the remaining time of a timer?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, time

I have a timer that enables a button in 45 seconds

```
 Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 45), EnableButtonResend);


 private bool EnableButtonResend()
    {
        IsEnabledResend = true;
        return true;
    }
```

everything works perfectly and I would like to show in a label the remaining time before the button is enabled. something like please wait XX in seconds to resend. Does anyone know how to do it? 
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), EnableButtonResend);

int count = 0;

private bool EnableButtonResend()
{ 
    if(count < 45) {
        IsEnabledResend = true;
        count++;
        Button.SetText((45 - count) + " seconds remaining");
        return true;
    }
    // Do your stuff or reset state
    count = 0;
    return false;
}
```

If you return `true` in `EnableButtonResend` the timer will keep recurring, so set the interval every second and you'll have a callback to change the label when you need.

Comment: perfect! only that IsEnabledResend must be = false; until the condition count <45; thank you very much

Comment: Welcome! I'm glad it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can have the time of enabling in a variable:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(45);
Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 45), EnableButtonResend);
SownRemaining();
```

And while that time has not reached call a method that changes the label text:

```
void ShowRemaing()
{
    int a = (int)((dt - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds);
    if(a > 0)
    {
    SomeLabel.Text = $"{a} Seconds to enable";
    Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), ShowRemaing);
    }
}

 private bool EnableButtonResend()
    {
        IsEnabledResend = true;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Mobayen, may I chat with you in an appropriate time? I need some consultative help.

Comment: yep. just create a chat and invite me

Comment: thank you. but I don't know how to chat in stackoverflow!

Comment: I can not find any way.